# Is WebSocket compatible with HTTP/3

Tags: http, websocket, http3

The upcoming HTTP/3 standard is no longer based on TCP, but on the QUIC protocol. WebSocket is based on TCP and is initiated as HTTP update.

Is a WebSocket connection initiated as HTTP/3 update based on QUIC instead of TCP? Or is it not possible to update a HTTP/3 connection to a WebSocket connection?

Comment: The current WebSocket protocol requires TCP, though there is nothing stopping *implementations* from including support for QUIC at the transport layer. There are proposals to adapt the WebSocket protocol to QUIC/HTTP3, though.

Comment: I think a new approach is taking over: a replacement for WebSockets and WebRTC that supports both Reliable streams and Unreliable datagrams optionally via quic: https://wicg.github.io/web-transport/

For now I think you're best off using SSE (EventSource) for QUIC based server sent events

Answer (score 22, accepted):

UPDATE: 2023: as of the writing of this post there is a relatively new specification RFC9220 for websockets built on top of HTTP3 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc9220/ .

- Please note RFC 9220 is a specification and so does not help answer questions like: does web-browser X/Y/Z (or library A/B/C, or operating system D/E/F) support this?

---

Since this is the top search result for "http3 websockets", I want to keep the answers up-to-date.

As of December 2021, there is now an [IETF draft](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-httpbis-h3-websockets-02.html) that amends [RFC8441](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8441) (Bootstrapping WebSockets with HTTP/2) with the adjustments necessary for HTTP/3. If the draft *is* accepted, there will be a standardized way for WebSockets to be initiated over HTTP/3.

The draft is on its second revision and will expire in July 2022 if there are no further revisions and it is not accepted by that time.

Comment: Now moving to RFC9220

Answer (score 9):

Currently only HTTP/1.1 is supported by the [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4) to be used for connection upgrade.

> Once a connection to the server has been established (including a
> connection via a proxy or over a TLS-encrypted tunnel), the client
> MUST send an opening handshake to the server.  The handshake consists
> of an HTTP Upgrade request, along with a list of required and
> optional header fields.  The requirements for this handshake are as
> follows.
>
> 1. The handshake MUST be a valid HTTP request as specified by
>    [RFC2616].
> 2. The method of the request MUST be GET, and the HTTP version MUST
>    be at least 1.1.

However, there are proposals to support HTTP/2 as well as HTTP/3 (as Remy Lebeau mentioned in comment above).

Comment: For HTTP/2 this answer is slightly outdated, see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8441

Comment: I don't get this answer. Point 2 clearly states "at least 1.1". There's no reason for Websockets not to work over Http3.